# asp.net element.style issue with height property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have an asp.net mvc project where have a table with fixed header and first two columns. It was write with jquery-ui, where I'm use ui-widget-content as main class for my td elements. Header display perfect, but my td's have the next property

```
element.style {
    height: 140px;
}
```

And I have no idea from where they appear.

I was try to add next piece of code

```
    $(".ui-widget-content").each(function () {
        $(this).css("height", "40px");
    });
```

But it's only replace from 140px to 40px without any changes by sight. I have no idea where is my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

element.style is the style that's defines on the element - directly - using style=""
So you should check your JavaScript or HTML for it.

Another issue is that you don't have to use "each" in order to set a height you could just go with

```
$(".ui-widget-content").css("height", "40px");
```

and you will have the same result.

Another issue with `$(".ui-widget-content").css("height", "40px");` is that in case that you will include other widgets in your page they are also going to have  height = 40 so it is not very convenient to use it.

In general try to avoid inline styling. It is a better practice to create a class that will define all styling properties!

Answer (score 0):

As much I'm against `!important` value, this is the scenario where you should use it.

`element.style` indicates that 140px height is inline or setted by JavaScript. If by Javascript, the code may be executed after your code ($.each).